# Round up the cents field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the situation, I'm entering a dollar amount within the text field something similar to the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="qtr-revenue-<?php echo $qtr ?>" id="qtr-revenue-<?php echo $qtr ?>" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="<?php echo App_Number::formatCurrency($qtrNumbers['Revenue'], 2, '', true, '') ?>" />
```

However, the following thing is happening, I'm able to properly format for example 9,000,000.90 with no issues, however, whenever I mistakenly enter 9,000,000.90000099323, it formats the number to 9,000,000.900,000,993,23

How do I properly format the dollar amount from 9,000,000.90000099323 to 9,000,000.90?

Here is the javascript code that formats the number right now.

```
$(this).val(function (index, value) {
    return value
        .replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach. It's not supported in IE11 though.
Also you can play around with different currencies and their formats.

Here is some guides:
[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

```js
const number = "9,000,000.90000099323".replace(/,/g, '');
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(number));
```

So in your case it could be something like

```
$(this).val(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format("9,000,000.90000099323".replace(/,/g, '')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, I found a much simpler solution:

If I post the following code:

```
           if (revenue.toString().indexOf('.') != -1) {
                $(this).val(revenue.toFixed(2));
            }
```

This does the job that I'm looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Not an JS expert but I have a financial website and to make a number look like the following I use the code below
*1,139,447,000*

```
String(value).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,'$1,');
```

I believe you should be able to change the result by updating the regex in here